# MysqlException was unhandled C# LAST_INSERT_ID()

Tags: c#, winforms, persistence

Whenever I add the line: SET @last_id_owner = LAST_INSERT_ID();. it gives me the warning; MysqlException was unhandled in the line : cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
if I erase the line it works well.

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO owner (name,email,reward)"
             + " VALUES('" + owner.Name + "','" + owner.EMail + "'," + owner.Reward + ");SET @last_id_owner = LAST_INSERT_ID();";
connect();
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conexion);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
disconnect();
```

I need to obtain the last insert id and use it in an insert for another table.
Whats wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you have to notice is, your query will opens a wide door for [SqLInjection](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp). To avoind this you should use Parameterized queries. Then You can use  `LastInsertedId` of the `MySqlCommand` class to get the Last inserted ID. You can achieve both by using the following snippet:

```
// Parameterization implementation
String sql = "INSERT INTO owner (name,email,reward)"
    + " VALUES(@ownerName,@ownerMail,@ownerReward)";

MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conexion);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ownerName",MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value= owner.Name;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ownerMail", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = owner.EMail;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ownerReward", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = owner.Reward;

// Executing Query and getting last Inserted ID
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
long lastInsertedID = cmd.LastInsertedId;
```

Answer (score 0):

try with This Code It will help You... As You want.

```
 String sql = "INSERT INTO owner (name,email,reward)  VALUES('" + owner.Name + "','" + owner.EMail + "'," + owner.Reward + "); select LAST_INSERT_ID();";
            connect();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conexion);
            cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            disconnect();
```